# Как создать окно для вывода результата?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

Нужно создать программу с таким интерфейсом.
Как написать функцию, чтобы вывести результат? Наверное, тут вообще не entry, а какой-то другой виджет должен быть.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()

def formula():
    try:
        return entry_2.set(4/3*3.14*(entry.get()**3))
    except: messagebox.showinfo('Введите число')

title = Label(root, text = 'Программа для вычисления объема сферы')
title.configure(font = ('arial', 10, 'bold')) 
title.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

hint = Label(root, text = 'Введите радиус:')
hint.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

explanation = Label(root, text = 'Результат вычислений:')
explanation.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

but_result = Button(root, text = 'Вычислить', command = formula)
but_result.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

but_save = Button(root, text = 'Сохранить')
but_save.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
drop_down = ttk.Combobox(root, values = ['Текст', 'HTML'])
drop_down.current(0)
drop_down.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Можно и Entry. Только сделать её read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как это можно реализовать используя `Entry`.

`Entry` связать с переменной. Так проще менять её содержимое, чем через её методы `delete` и `insert`.

```
result_text = StringVar()
entry_2 = Entry(root, textvariable=result_text, state=DISABLED)
```

В функции не забывать содержимое `Entry` преобразовывать в число прежде чем чего-то там вычислять.

```
def formula():
    try:
        radius = int(entry.get())
        result_text.set(4/3*3.14*(radius**3))
    except: 
        messagebox.showerror('Ошибка', 'Введите число!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать `Label`. Вот пример:

```
result = Label(root)
result.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

result.config(text='ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕТЕ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ')
```